# Android Layout- Part of TextView goes off edge of screen

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, textview

I have a LinearLayout with a custom button and then another LinearLayout with two TextViews, which is always partly cut off on the edge of the screen. I have tried tons of different combinations of fill_parents, match_parents, and wrap_contents, as well as trying to add layout_weights, but nothing solved it, nor did any answer to any similar questions on this site. Here is my XML code, thanks for any help!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<com.goldtrimdevelopment.sites.google.com.interesthub.SquareButton
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/list_article_like_button"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_like_button"
        android:contentDescription="@string/like_button"
        android:padding="5dip" />
</com.goldtrimdevelopment.sites.google.com.interesthub.SquareButton>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/article_title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/article_link"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="12sp" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured from your xml file that you want the layout to be a custom button and to its right 2 textviews which are vertically linear, while the buttons and the textviews are horizontall linear. Try the following values in your layout. I think it must solve the issue.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" or "wrap content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >
```

and the next linear layout as

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
```

and for both textviews set

```
android:layout_width="150dp"
```

try it and let me know.

Comment: This worked ok, it does cut off the text view, but it is a pain to manually set the value and try to get it so it perfectly goes to the screens edge. Is there a way to accomplish the same thing without a manual value?

Comment: i could not figure out a way around maybe try reducing the textsize. pls mark the answer as correct if it helped. :)